# Label not showing command line output in python 2.7 on ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, shell, ubuntu

I want the result of command line to be shown in the label, right now it shows nothing, if I use `call` instead of `check_output` then it shows 0.

```
def find():
        take=text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        info = subprocess.check_output("grep -i '{take}' /var/log/syslog >   logs/uzklausa/$(date +%d_%m_%Y.txt)".format(take=take), shell=True)
        w = Label(root, text = info)
        w.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Is it because I use wrong command for subprocess or is it because I save into the file and therefore it can't show me the answer.

Comment: It is very hard for us to work out whether the command is wrong based only on what you are presenting here. To find out if it is the wrong command, print the command you are passing to `subprocess.check_output()`, paste it into a command line, and see what happens.

Comment: well, it says nothing, just that command was completed successfuly, but the info is taken from the syslog file, so I need that info shown in label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is piping its output to `logs/uzklausa/20_05_2017.txt`. So the data you want doesn't go to the screen when you run it by hand, and for the same reason, it doesn't get returned by `check_output()`. Either open the file you are piping to and read the data out of it, or don't redirect the command output to a file.